# How to include template wrapped in a div based on browser URL in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

How can I include a template based and wrap it in a div based on the URL? It seems that I am missing the point somewhere here.

I have the following link in my template:

```
<a href="/settings/workflows"><i class="mdi-action-settings"></i>Workflows</a>
```

and in a different section in the very same template I want to include a template that reflects the URL, e.g.

```
{{> Template.dynamic template=route}}
```

`route` is a helper function that parses the URL and returns the template name based on the second index of the URL, in the link above it will result in the template `workflow` for example.

Now I got it working to a point where it works ONE time - on startup but as soon I click the link, the browser URL changes but the actual content doesn't - the helper also never receives a refresh either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to my co-worker Shakib - we got it figured out - basically I can achieve this with regions and yieldTemplates.

I made an example and pushed it to my github:

https://github.com/flyandi/meteor-iron-router-example

Basically the secret is to configure the static route and use the yieldTemplate as region, e.g.:

```
['profile', 'billing', 'account'].forEach(function(path) {


    Router.route('/settings/' + path, {

        yieldTemplates: {
            'settings': {to: 'body'}
        },

        template: path,

    });

});
```

Hope that helps!